# Getting the full path of a running PID with C/C++ without using the system function (Linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, process, pid

So I want to be able to get the full path of a running process (which I have the process ID for) without using any commands on the command line. Anyone has any ideas on how to do this?

I do have the PID, is there any function that by passing the PID can return the full path of that process as a char *?

Comment: What OS/platform are we talking about here? Answers for Windows will be entirely wrong for Linux (and vice versa).

Comment: @JerryCoffin sorry, Linux, any distribution

Comment: If you stick to the functions offered in the C standard, there's not a single one for the purpose. You must use some system function.

Comment: @Alexey: I think they mean `system(3)`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Oh, confusion! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `readlink("/proc/<pid>/exe", buf, bufsize)` to get the path to `<pid>`'s executable. This works on Linux, provided `procfs` is available (it usually is).

Example usage:

```
int get_exe_for_pid(pid_t pid, char *buf, size_t bufsize) {
    char path[32];
    sprintf(path, "/proc/%d/exe", pid);
    return readlink(path, buf, bufsize);
}
```

Returns `-1` on failure and sets `errno`.

Comment: Do I need root access to use this function? Or does it depend on the process? Is readlink() from a standard C library?

Comment: You need to be the same user as the process, or root (AFAIK).

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. The only downside is that I have to use a fixed size for the path variable, no biggie though..

Comment: If you need a fixed size, use `PATH_MAX`.

Comment: @nneonneo: No, by default /proc/<pid> is readable by everyone.  Many files within it are only readble by the owner, but not exe, which is a symlink readable by anyone.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I'm not sure that's the case. On a Linux machine I have access to, `readlink /proc/1/exe` (for the `init` process) fails from an unprivileged account, even though `/proc/1/exe` is `chmod 777`.

Comment: @neuro: `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` may not contain the actual executable filename, since a process is free to set `argv[0]` to anything it wants when it does `execve`.

Answer (score 0):

[man 3 realpath](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realpath)

This expands all symlink and directory relative token. Sadly, it is GNU specific, I use it with `-std=gnu99`, like `printf("%s\n", realpath("/proc/self/exe", NULL))`.